# How do I combine 2 sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could someone please explain how I would go about combining 2 sets(or link me to some beginner reading material regarding this). For example:

Let $P = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 6\}, Q = \{x \in \mathbb{N} | x \leq 4\}$

$P \cap Q$

$P \cup Q$

$P \setminus  Q$

I understand what the resultant values will be but I don't understand the syntax/how I could express the 2 sets as 1 set which satisfies both sets.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  are you looking for the definitions of $\cap$, $\cup$, and $\setminus$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the bracket notation to enumarate its members:

$P\cap Q=\{1,2,3,4\}$

etc.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there are only a handful of elements in any of the sets in question, so simply listing all members inside of set brackets should work great.

In general, writing down notation for a set you have in mind can be tricky, which is why set builder notation is so flexible. If I want to intersect the set $\mathbb{N}$ with the real interval $[3.5,\infty)$, I could write different things:

$\{4,5,\ldots\}$

$\{n\in\mathbb{N} \,\,|\,\, n \geq 3.5 \}$

$\{n\in\mathbb{N} \,\,|\,\, n\geq 4 \}$

or simply:

$\mathbb{N} \cap [3.5,\infty)$

In general, there's not always just one correct way to do it.